# Angular post to server $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

Hello here's my json :

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAAAAA",
        "date": "28-03-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "BBBBBB",
        "date": "20-12-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "CCCCCC",
        "date": "09-01-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "DDDDDD",
        "date": "21-07-2016",
    }
]
```

My javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('names.json').then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.names = data.data;
            console.log($scope.names);
        }
    );
    $scope.postfunction = function() {
        $http.post('serwerUrl',{'name':name})
        .success(function(data){console.log('data success');
    };
});
```

HTML :

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td>{{name.date}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="postfunction(name.name)">POST</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I want do is when I click the button "POST" name.name post to server. I try $http.post in postfunction(), but I get error "(501 Unsupported method ('OPTIONS'))" and "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin "in console.

Comment: success is deprecated in Angular >= 1.5

Answer (score 1):

The server / api does not support the options header, this is CORS.
Before each request angular is performing a OPTIONS header which is basically a handshake. It asks the server if the request it wants to do is allowed.

Make sure you read more about CORS and the server implements what is necessary.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS